# Save the screenshot of desktop in Microsoft Word using Sikuli

Tags: automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am new to Sikuli and I had one doubt. Consider I am using Sikuli and written some sentences in Microsoft Word using Sikuli (by using the editor command). Now I want to take a screenshot of the Desktop and paste in the Microsoft Word file after the sentences I have written.

Can this be done in Sikuli?

Comment: what has this got to do this java?

Comment: ok sorry by mistake i have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Word window is already in focus, just do:

```
type(Key.PRINTSCREEN)
type("v", KeyModifier.CTRL)
```